# concat multiple rows in one field

Tags: mysql

I have table Test

```
sso     ID
-------------
1234    XV
1235    PL17
1234    PL17
1239    XV
```

I'm trying to concatenate all IDs having same sso. I have developed the output using `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Here is the query

```
SELECT sso, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) FROM samesso GROUP BY sso
```

But I want to do this without function.

Can I have any syggestions or ideas to do this ?

Comment: You're asking how to do an SQL aggregate query without using an SQL aggregate function.  With respect, that's a strange request. It's a bit like saying, "I  want to drive my car to New York City, but I want to do it without using tires." It will help us give you an answer if you explain your constraints in a bit more detail.

Comment: Maybe you could show your expected result also, maybe we misunderstood the question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables:

```
SELECT sso, MAX(group_ids)
FROM (
  SELECT sso,
         @group := IF(@sso = sso, CONCAT(@group, ',', ID),
                      IF(@sso := sso, ID, ID)) AS group_ids
 FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sso := 0, @group := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY sso) AS t
GROUP BY sso
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fba72/7)